# How do you find the error generated by a backbone fetch

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I'm new to backbone but I've written a basic model and when trying to fetch data for my model. I know the server is returning the data but fetch is calling the error callback.

That's fine but I don't know how I can find what error is being generated.

Here's the relevant code:

```
  mUser = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: CURRENT_URL+'user',
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        age: 22,
        email: ''
    },
    initialize: function(){

    }
  });

  user = new mUser({'id':1});

  var x = user.fetch({
    error:   function(model, xhr, options){
       alert('Error on fetch')
       console.log(xhr.responseText);
    },
    success: function(model, response, options) {
        alert(user.toJSON());
    }
  })
  console.log('x email',x.email)
```

As I mentioned, the responseText does have the data I expect to see from the server, which is:

{'id':'1','name':'joe','age':'25','email':'joe@example.com'}

Maybe I should mention that I'm, doing this as part of a PhoneGap android app. I don't think it's significant to the problem I'm having but it does limit my debugging options.

Comment: did you check http status code returned?

Comment: The server sends a 200. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: what's the CURRENT_URL value and how are you monitoring the requests?

Comment: I'd suggest debugging by setting a break point in the `Backbone.sync` function. See why it's calling the error (look at the callstack).

Comment: CURRENT_URL = "http://"+CURRENT_IP+":"+CURRENT_PORT+"/"

Which is just the IP of the server I'm running on my local machine. I know the URL is correct for two reasons: 1) the server reacts to the request by writing it's response to the console which I can see and 2) responseText has the value the sever returned.

Isn't there a way to get backbone to just tell me what the error is?

Comment: you can print the xhr object to log

Comment: @WiredPrairie I should have mentioned this before but I'm running this in an Android emulator so setting breakpoints is not very easy. I updated my original question to include this fact.

Comment: @soulcheck is there a specific field you're interested in? If I just log the xhr object I just get [object Object]. I can log xhr.status which gives me "200" and I can log xhr.statusText which gives me: "OK" so I don't think there's anything wrong with the HTTP aspect of my request. Yet backbone is obviously not happy and won't tell me why.

Comment: You might be getting a `parsererror`. Can you add a `complete` callback and log the `textStatus` parameter? e.g. `complete: function(xhr, textStatus) { console.log(textStatus); }`

Comment: @dl__ i posted that before you said what platform you're on. Some js loggers (ie chome one) allow inspection of printed objects.

Comment: You can't run your code outside of an Android emulator (at least this tiny portion?)

Comment: @WiredPrairie I suppose it's possible but it's not as simple as double clicking on the index.html file so it comes up in a browser. When you do that the fetch fails because of cross domain issues. Under PhoneGap I can make ajax calls to any server so the HTML/javascript doesn't live on the server where the data I want to access does.

I may have to figure out a way to move the code back and forth though because it sure would be nice to have firebug.

Comment: @Ben Yay! It says "parseerror". Do you know how to get anymore detail? Also, how did you know about complete()? It's not mentioned here: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch. Is there more complete documentation somewhere (other than the code)?

Comment: @Ben OK, I found that my server was returning badly formatted JSON. Ben, if you create an actual stackoverflow answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Backbone uses jQuery.ajax by default to send requests. `complete` is a standard callback that jQuery accepts. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ (sorry, I don't think I can link directly to the `complete` callback in the api docs)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are probably getting a `parsererror` when jQuery tries to parse the JSON response from your server. To check if you're getting a `parsererror`, add a `complete` callback and check the `textStatus` parameter. e.g.

```
user.fetch({
  complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
    console.log(textStatus);
  }
});
```

Comment: When I added this, the value I got was for textStatus was just "error".  I was getting a 200 from the server.  In my case problem was that I was just loading the web page from file:// and calling the REST service by http://.